# rename `key` to `access_token` in django-rest-auth?

Tags: django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, ember-simple-auth, django-rest-auth

My `django-rest-auth` on authentication sends the following response

```
{"key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Now i am using `ember-simple-auth` specifically `oauth2-password-grant` for authentication which expects `access_token` in response body. After looking at source code of ember js [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/1.3.0/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js#L385), i found out that the value `access_token` is defined as string and cannot be changed. My question is how can i implement authentication using the two stack. Is there any way that i can rename `key` to `access_token` in django ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `MyLoginView` which subclasses the original `LoginView` from django-rest-auth and create custom Serializer that returns the `access_token` field.

Something like this:

**my_app/serializers.py**

```
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Token model.
    """
    access_token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('access_token',)

    def get_access_token(self, obj):
        return object.key
```

**my_app/views.py**

```
from rest_auth.views import LoginView
from my_app.serializers import MyTokenSerializer

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_response_serializer(self):
        return MyTokenSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from my_app.views import MyLoginView

url(r'^login/$', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='my_login'),
```